# How to download files with white space on name on Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to download a file from this URL:

https://renatoleite.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/documents/Test Document.pdf

The browser is changing the URL to this:

https://renatoleite.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/documents/Test%20Document.pdf

My file in the blob storage has the name: `Test Document.pdf`

So, when I clicks to download, the Azure say that file not exist:

> The specified resource does not exist.

Probably because the browser is trying to get the file with "%20" in the name.

How I can solve this?

Comment: Blob names are case-sensitive & Reserved URL characters must be properly escaped. Are both executed correctly?

Comment: I don't think `%20` is the reason. Can you share the actual URL of the blob?

Comment: The blob name is correct, files without white space in the name are working correctly :\

Comment: Can you share how did you upload this file?

Comment: @GauravMantri I used the Azure API to C#

Comment: Ok. What is the blob container ACL? It should not be `Private`. I just tried `https://renatoleite.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?restype=container&comp=list` and it told me that resource does not exist. It would mean 2 things: 1) The container by the name `mycontainer` does not exist or 2) It's ACL is private.

Comment: @GauravMantri the "mycontainer" name was just an example. The correct name is "novajus".

Comment: So I tried with this blob container name and I still got the same error. Does this container exist? What's the ACL on that container?

Comment: @GauravMantri I changed the ACL to container now

Comment: So I just tried it and I was able to download `Etiqueta de processos (2).pdf` without any problems. Regarding `Test Document.pdf`, it is actually saved as `Test%20Document.pdf` (I believe it was URL encoded before being uploaded). Please try with that.

Comment: @GauravMantri is true, I'll check it... Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, if you want to upload the file space name by using azure storage api, it will auto encoded the name(replace the space with %20) when uploading it.

You could see below example:

I uploaded the Test Document.pdf to the blob storage.

```
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve a reference to a container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("brando");

        // Create the container if it doesn't already exist.
        container.CreateIfNotExists();

        // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("Test Document.pdf");

        // Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file.
        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"D:\Test Document.pdf"))
        {
            blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
        }
```

Then I suggest you could use [storage explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/)(right click the properties to see its url) or azure portal to see its url from the blob's property.

The url like this:

You could find it replace the space with %20.

[image]

Comment: But, one cannot add %20% manually to all these images. For 1/2 images it's fine but if you have a lot of these then its not feasible.